# I am having trouble transferring my Tether USD from coin-base wallet to everywhere

Tags: wallets, coinbase, usdt

I'm trying to send Tether USD to another wallet or exchange.
I try to send to a Binance address (I have the same error with Coinbase address) but I receive this error:
0.00038 BNB (0,17 USD) may be required for the transaction. Please deposit more ETH.
In my coinbase wallet I have 133$ in ETH so what is the problem?
I don't understand.
Can you help me please?

[image: send]
[image: my wallet]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need the cryptocurrency of the blockchain to pay the gasfee if you are on binance blockchain you will need BNB to pay the gas fee

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase wallet may have some bugs if you are operating on testnets or L2 networks, for example, Arbitrum One network. I noticed that it tries to deduct fees from the L1 Ethereum mainnet even if I am doing transactions on Arbitrum, and returns an error of insufficient balance. If the problem persists without finding a solution or adjustment for this, consider using Metamask if there is an option.